# repeat a function when it finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that hides and shows divs.

How can i set it up, when the function finishes running, then it should start again?

```
function rotateimages() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    restoreOriginal()
    $('.main2').css('background-image', 'url(/img/2017/home_main_vacation.gif)');
  }, 3500);
  setTimeout(function() {
    restoreOriginal()
    $('.main5').css('background-image', 'url(/img/2017/home_main_tickets.gif)');
  }, 12500);
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do when it finishes running? Put it inside the `setTimeout()`?

Comment: have the function call itself from inside the function. it's called recursion.

Comment: The way you indent code is... creative, but not very readable.

Comment: You could use `css` to render expected result. What does `restoreOriginal`  do? Can you include `html`, `css` at Question?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to perpetually alternate between home_main_vacation and home_main_tickets, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to alternate between the two images, forever, the simplest solution is just to call the function from itself at the end of your second timeout. This, as [I wrestled a bear once](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1444609/i-wrestled-a-bear-once) mentioned, is a principle called recursion.

```
function rotateimages() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    restoreOriginal()
    $('.main2').css('background-image', 'url(/img/2017/home_main_vacation.gif)');
  }, 3500);
  setTimeout(function() {
    restoreOriginal()
    $('.main5').css('background-image', 'url(/img/2017/home_main_tickets.gif)');
    rotateimages()//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Recurse here!
  }, 12500);
}
```

This way, your rotateimages function will be called every 12.5 seconds. So your behavior will be wait 3.5 seconds, show main_vacation, wait 9 more seconds, show main_tickets and recall. Repeated forever.

If you only want to repeat a few times, you can set counters, etc. and place the recursive function call in a conditional.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `css` `animation`, `transition` to render expected result.

```css
.main2, .main5 {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.main2 {
  transition: background-image 3.5s ease-in-out;
  animation: main2 3.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

.main5 {
  transition: background-image 12.5s ease-in-out;
  animation: main5 12.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes main2 {
  from {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats);
  }
  to {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/technics);
  }
}

@keyframes main5 {
  from {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/city);
  }
  to {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main2"></div>
<br>
<div class="main5"></div>
```